# How can get title of anchor in controller method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a quiz system site but I have a problem: How can I get title of anchor in controller, I want to save quiz name in title and want to read quiz name back, so how can I solve this issue?
Code is given below:

```
    foreach ($quizname as $value1) {
        if( $value['subject_id']== $value1['subject_id'])
        {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo anchor('Quiz/get_quizname',$value1["quiz_name"],array('title'=>$value1["quiz_name"]))?></li>
         <?php
          } 
    }
```

Controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Quiz extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
            $this->load->model('subject_data');
        }
        public function index()
        {

        }
        public function get_quizname()
        {
            $data=array();
            $data['quizname']=$_GET['title'];
            $this->load->view('test',$data);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

test view:

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass the `$value1["quiz_name"]` in your `anchor`'s url like this

```
echo anchor('Quiz/get_quizname/'.$value1["quiz_name"], value1["quiz_name"], 'title'=$value1["quiz_name"]);
```

then CI will use it as a parameter for your `get_quizname()` method. Now you can use it just like any other param in a function.

```
public function get_quizname($name = null)
        {
            $data['quizname'] = $name ? $name : 'No quiz name';
            $this->load->view('test',$data);
        }
```